# remote debugging problem in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging

I have local my projects asp.net open in visual studio 2010. And also copy this project to IIS folder in remote hosting. Cause in hosting directory I don't have VS so I copy there remote debugger application. I connect from my Visual Studio to IIS process on hosting, but any of breakpoints not fire.

Why ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I connected using the Transport in the "Attach to Process" dialog set to "Remote (native only with no authentication)".  I was able to connect to the IIS process (w3wp.exe for IIS6 on Win2K3), but no breakpoints were hit when I navigated within the web app.

To get it working, I changed the Transport to "Default".  Then I ran into numerous issues with successfully connecting to the Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor.  But once I resolved them all and was able to get the list of processes from the remote machine, I could connect to W3WP.exe and voila, my breakpoints started working and I was able to debug normally.

You don't provide much detail on your local and remote configuration, so this just a guess whether it might help.